# Unity3D - Unable to run test thru command line

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nunit

I am trying to run my Unity Unit test with the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.3f1\Editor\Unity.exe" -runTests -quit -batchmode -projectPath "X:\MyProject" -logFile ./log.txt -testResults ./results.xml
```

However no reports are generated or message is given to the CMD console.

Here is what I have in the `log.txt`:

https://pastebin.com/aaZBkmUT

Why can't I run the tests? What am I doing wrong?

P.S.
What does that mean `ERROR Failed to connect to local IPC` ? May this be the cause of my issue somehow?

Comment: Previously coming from a [question you deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62950944/7111561) ... now you did not pass the argument `-testPlatform` is this intended?

Comment: `-testPlatform` is coming with default EditMode where my tests are. With this argument or not there is no change.

Comment: I see just wanted to be sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it eihter without `-quit`

They don't have it in the [example](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.test-framework@1.1/manual/reference-command-line.html). The thing is that afaik Tests run async so you might just be shutting down Unity before the results are available

---

Alternatively I think you could add the `-runSynchronously`

> If included, the test run will run tests synchronously, guaranteeing that all tests runs in one editor update call. Note that this is only supported for EditMode tests, and that tests which take multiple frames (i.e. [UnityTest] tests, or tests with [UnitySetUp] or [UnityTearDown] scaffolding) will be filtered out.

to make sure your editor stays alive until the tests are done synchronously

Comment: Yes. removing -quit solved the issue. results.xml was generated. Do you have any idea how I can print the results in the console intead of the results.xml ?

Comment: I think Unity itself doesn't support that but if you are using CMD you could just run `type ./log.txt` or on bash `cat ./log.txt`

Comment: However how can I understand that I have failed test and make my gitlab CI pipeline to fail? Atm no matter I have failing tests my pipeline passes ?